# Comparing/Matching ACLs

Tags: windows, security, permissions, powershell, access-control-list

Rather it be through PowerShell or another tool here is what I'm trying to accomplish and where it stems from.

We have Junction points on one volume and the Target folders on another volume.
Permissions do not follow once a Junction is created or a target.

What I'd like to do is get the ACL of the Junc and get the ACL of the target folder.
Compare them and apply the users/groups that are missing from one another with the proper permissions.

I have the steps I want to take. just not sure the proper way at the end to add the single or multiple missing users/groups to the other.

Steps:
1) Get Junction folder
2) Get Junction folder ACL
3) Get Target folder
4) Get Target folder ACL
5) Compare ACL lists rather compare-object in powershell or however.
Does JunctionACL have a user/group that is missing from Target Folder?
If so, Apply that user/group to Target
Now vice-versa.
Does TargetACL have a user/group that is missing from Junction ACL?

Thank you in advance. Hope this was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `help Get-Acl -Full`. Get-ACL will give you the ACL object, which you can then manipulate and then use `Set-Acl` to apply that object to a different target folder.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of these. My biggest concern is the comparison and then applying the difference. I'll see if the -full gives me anything else to work with.